If {} allows any non-nullish value, why doesn't `FC<{}>` allow any properties?
I saw the following viewpoint on the React TypeScript Cheatsheet website: "An empty interface, {} and Object all represent "any non-nullish value"—not "an empty object" as you might think."
For example:
let value: {};

value = 1;
value = "foo";
value = () => alert("foo");
value = {};
value = { foo: "bar" };

value = undefined; // Error Type
value = null;  // Error Type

The example above shows that when the type is {}, you can match strings, functions, and any non-empty values.
So, as shown in the code below, when I define the type of the Child component as FC<{}>, my props type becomes {}, which seems to imply: "You can pass strings, functions, and any non-empty values as props to Child."
However, when I use the Child component in the parent component and try to set the props of Child to { id: '1111' }, it throws an error.
const Child:FC<{}> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      Child
    </div>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    {/**Error: Type '{ id: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.**/}
    <Child id={'111'}/>
  );
}

However, the code below works fine.
let props: {}
props = {id: '111'}

I would like to receive a fundamental explanation.
==========================================================
I've come up with an answer that seems to convince myself, and I'm sharing it here for everyone to consider.
We know that when we write a <MyComponent/>, it gets transpiled into createElement().
This is the declaration of createElement:
interface Attributes {
  key?: Key | null | undefined;
}

function createElement<P extends {}>(
  type: FunctionComponent<P>,
  props?: Attributes & P | null,
  ...children: ReactNode[]
): FunctionComponentElement<P>;

Suppose we have a component:
const MyComponent = (props: {}) => <div>I am a child component</div>;

Originally, the props were non-null, but when passed to createElement, props became Attributes & P, which is {key?: Key | null | undefined}. At this point, props no longer represents a non-null value.
return (
  <div className="App">
    <MyComponent a="1" /> //error
    <MyComponent key={"1"} /> //ok
  </div>
);
```jsx


I think this article would be useful on using FC. Maybe you do not need FC at all? https://www.totaltypescript.com/you-can-stop-hating-react-fc

Things to note:

React functional components are functions
Functions in React are contravariant.

Quote from the blog:

Contravariance is a rule that enforces that a function’s input type
must be a supertype of the input type of the function it’s being
assigned to

Because of the above property of TypeScript:
The below will compile with an error:
type EmptyObject = {};

type Func = (f : EmptyObject) => void;

const func : Func = ({ id }) => {
console.log({id})
};

and this one will work without errors:
type IdObject = { id : string}

type Func2 = (f : IdObject) => void;


const func2 : Func2 = ({}) => {
};

And that is exactly the behaviour you see above.
Playground

When you define a React component with FC<{}>, you're saying that this component accepts NO props at all. This is because {} is interpreted as the props object cannot contain any keys. So {} means no keys.
The type {} means that the props object is an empty object. When you try to pass { id: '111' }, TypeScript raises an error because id is not a key that {} allows—since {} is supposed to have no keys at all!
If you want a Child component to accept any props, here is how you can do it:
const Child: FC<Record<string, unknown>> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      Child
    </div>
  );
}

Record<string, unknown> is a TypeScript utility type that represents an object with string keys and values of any type. It is equivalent to { [key: string]: unknown }. unknown specifies that the values can be of any type, but their exact type is not known at compile time.
or if you want the Child to accept id as a prop:
const Child: FC<{ id: string }> = ({ id }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      Child with ID: {id}
    </div>
  );
}


I disagree with what you said,
'When you define a React component using FC<{}>,
you are saying that the component does not accept any props at all.'
Because if the idea that {} represents a non-empty value is correct,
then when I define a React component using FC<{}>,
I am saying that the component accepts any non-empty props.
Therefore, it should allow me to pass an object with an id as a prop to the Child component.
This is exactly what confuses me.

When you define a React component using FC<{}>, you're saying that the component does not expect any specific props. But this does not mean that you can pass arbitrary props. Instead, it means that no props are expected, so TypeScript will flag any prop you try to pass as an error. There is a tiny difference between React's FC<{}> and Typescript's {}. {} as a type does not mean "any non-empty object"

As a standalone type, {} is flexible and can technically allow any non-nullish value, but when used in the context of FC<{}>, it becomes restrictive and enforces that no props are passed.

let props: {}; props = {id: '111'} is correct, but FC<{}>; <Child id={'111'}/> is wrong. If the difference you mentioned truly exists, then it must be an issue with FC. I can't figure it out, but I will memorize it anyway :)

The question is, why? This is not answered. Why does it "become restrictive"? Normally you'd need to use Record<string, never> to specify an empty object, why not here? What mechanism causes this discrepancy (how is FC defined internally to cause this to happen), where is it documented, and could this gotcha apply to situations other than FC too? OP asked for a "fundamental explanation", but this is merely an "it is how it is" type of answer.

I did some digging afterwards and this is what I found out. FC<{}> intersects the {} with props from component. An intersection with {} does not add any new properties to the type and effectively limits it to "no properties are required."

In our codebase we usually avoid FC all together. Me and another fellow developer decided to ditch it. This https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8177#issue-537764080 and this https://www.totaltypescript.com/you-can-stop-hating-react-fc helped us reach that decision.

@AntonijaŠimić 安东尼娅·西米奇 Where did you find: "FC<{}> intersects the {} with props from the component. An intersection with {} does not add any new properties to the type and effectively limits it to 'no properties are required.'"

I haven't found it anywhere particularly written like that. I concluded it from multiple resources.

@SuCan What you are experiencing is basically excess property checks for JSX elements. While the type {id: number} is assignable to {}, writing let props: {} = {id: 111}; is still an error. Same for react components and function calls.
